# Windows Runtime Component + Azure Tables

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, azure-storage

I want to use Azure tables in my Windows Runtime Component project. It is a Background Agent for my Windows 8.1 RT app. When I try to define my **TableEntity** derived class:

```
public class CustomEntity : TableEntity
```

I get this error:

*Windows Runtime class 'CustomEntity' has an invalid base type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableEntity'. Classes must derive either from System.Object or from a composable Windows Runtime Class. Implementation inheritance is not allowed.*

I also tried deriving from **ITableEntity** but then I get this error:

*Type 'WindowsRuntimeComponent4.CustomEntity' implements interface 'Microsoft.Windows.AzureStorage.Table.ITableEntity', which is not a Windows Runtime Interface.  All interfaces that are implemented by exported types must be Windows Runtime interfaces.*

I can get Azure tables to work in the main Windows 8.1 RT app, an equivalent Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight App, and also the Background Agent for the Phone app. Anyone know why it won't work for Windows Runtime Component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Runtime Components aren't supported by Azure Storage Client Library. This class derivation limitation is one of the reasons that the Component isn't supported.

Comment: I can use Azure Blob Storage in Windows Runtime Components though.