# Send Device Location to the Azure Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8, geolocation, windows-phone-8.1

I have written background task to track location every defined time period. I want to send current location to the Azure as a background task. How can I achieve that. I used Azure Table Storage to store other details in foreground. It can not be used in background task. Any suggestion how can I send current location to Azure.

Comment: What do you mean by "how can I send current location to Azure?" You mean, how to transmit data from a phone app to a backend app running in Azure? If that's the case... there's no right answer to this - it's a very broad question with lots of possible solutions. Maybe you could edit the question to talk about what you've tried?

Comment: I think they are commenting on Azure Table Storage not working in the background task, even though it works in the foreground. I came across this my issue myself. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32545482/windows-runtime-component-azure-tables

Answer (score 0):

Use Azure Blob Storage instead of Azure Table Storage. That will work in both the Foreground & Background. Link [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/). Just store what you need to store as text, perhaps as CSV, XML, or JSON.

FYI if you store user location data in Azure you won't be able to automatically associate it with a user, anonymized or otherwise. You'd have to get the user to generate their own User ID. You could also store user location data in either Local or Roaming Settings, and this is automatically associated with each user of your app.